# Why does the axis change when I save the image as eps?

Tags: plotting, export, eps-format

```
xx = Range[10, 120, 10];yy = Range[0, 3.5, 0.3];wnHz = ((kf kr L^2 + (a kf - b kr) m v^2)/(Jz m v^2))^0.5/3.14/    2 /. {v -> vKph1/3.6};wnfun[vKph1_] = wnHz;pic3 = Plot[{wnfun[vKph1]}, {vKph1, 10, 120},   PlotStyle -> {Red, {Thickness[0.01]}}, PlotRange -> All,   PlotLabel -> "Vx-wn", PlotLegends -> "Expressions",   AxesLabel -> {"Vx(kph)", "wn(Hz)"}, Ticks -> {xx, yy},   GridLines -> Automatic, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.01]]pic4 = Show[  Plot[{wnfun[vKph1]}, {vKph1, 10, 120},    BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 12,      FontFamily -> "Times"}, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Thickness[0.01]}},    PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Vx-wn",    PlotLegends -> "Expressions", AxesLabel -> {"Vx(kph)", "wn(Hz)"},    Ticks -> {xx, yy}, GridLines -> Automatic, Axes -> True,    AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.01],    ImageSize -> {72 QuantityMagnitude[Quantity[4, "Inches"]],      Automatic}], ListPlot[{{18.8, 2}}]]Export["wn随车速变化.eps", pic4]
```

**The following are the original image and the exported image.**
[image: The original image]
[image: Export map]

Comment: Good question and I don't have an answer for it. I'd just like to point out that the pdf export is more faithful. If you really need an eps, you might be able to  circumvent this issue by exporting to pdf and by applying external tools such as pdf2eps

Comment: thank you ,i 'll try.

Comment: I tried it, the picture is not clear after conversion.